# Bulk updating/inserting from a temporary table using CSV (SQL)

Tags: sql, csv

I am currently trying to use a bulk insert from a temporary table with information from a CSV and then add the details of this table into a current one (without having to drop the proper table as it contains information already) I have currently got this:

Please ignore the table being dropped at the start, this was for testing purposes. Now I am kind of at a stump as to what I would need to do next, would I simply want to use an update table and state the column names and use a FROM statement.

```
DROP TABLE #Currencies


CREATE TABLE #Currencies(
suffix nvarchar(50) NULL,
name nvarchar(50) NULL,
iso nvarchar(50) NULL)
GO

BULK INSERT #Currencies
FROM 'C:\Documents and Settings\ntaylor\Desktop\Currencies.csv'
WITH(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO

ALTER TABLE #Currencies
ADD version_number int NOT NULL default 1,
[precision] int NULL,
cur_id  [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL default newid(),
exchange_rate decimal(19,5) NULL,
[default] bit NULL
GO


UPDATE #Currencies
SET [precision] = 2, exchange_rate = 1, [default] = 0

ALTER TABLE tbl_ecom_currency
ALTER COLUMN suffix nvarchar(50)

INSERT INTO tbl_ecom_currency (suffix, name, iso, version_number, [precision], cur_id, exchange_rate, [default])
SELECT  suffix, name, iso, version_number, [precision], cur_id, exchange_rate, [default]
FROM #Currencies
```

After executing this Query I seem to have the issue that it's creating all of the rows within the table but they don't seem to be proper rows as they are not there when i click edit top 200 rows however it seems to work when I choose to select top 1000 rows, but it creates them every single time so I have 1000+ rows now opposed to 150+

Comment: What's the update you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically I am trying to get the 3 new columns, name, prefix and iso as they are having information added into them (as I have only recently added in this information.) and insert this into the existing table without having to drop the original.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not just create a new table, copy the data across and drop the original? I think you are overcomplicating it. Seems like the way to go to me.

Comment: It's not my decision, I've been told to not drop the table :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a working method for this, using the following code I was able to execute it fine.

```
DROP TABLE #Currencies


CREATE TABLE #Currencies(
prefix nvarchar(50) NULL,
name nvarchar(50) NULL,
iso nvarchar(50) NULL)
GO

BULK INSERT #Currencies
FROM 'C:\Documents and Settings\ntaylor\Desktop\Currencies.csv'
WITH(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO

ALTER TABLE #Currencies
ADD version_number int NOT NULL default 1,
[precision] int NULL,
cur_id  [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL default newid(),
exchange_rate decimal(19,5) NULL,
created datetime NULL,
[default] bit NULL
GO


UPDATE #Currencies
SET [precision] = 2, exchange_rate = 1, [default] = 0, created = GetDate()
GO

ALTER TABLE tbl_ecom_currency
ALTER COLUMN prefix nvarchar(50)
GO


INSERT INTO tbl_ecom_currency (prefix, name, iso, version_number, [precision], cur_id, exchange_rate, [default], created)
SELECT  prefix, name, iso, version_number, [precision], cur_id, exchange_rate, [default], created
FROM #Currencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a way of linking the existing table with the temp table, e.g. on Name or Id.
Let's assume you already have Name in your existing table, and that the existing table is called Currencies.

At this point you will need to ALTER you Currencies table to include the new columns, if not already done so.

Then UPDATE Currencies along the lines of (assuming Name can be used to correlate Currencies and #Currencies):

```
UPDATE c SET c.prefix=t.prefix, c.iso=t.iso FROM Currencies c JOIN #Currencies t ON c.Name=t.Name
```

To better understand what's going on try a SELECT * with the same FROM clause (depending on DB and client there may be errors about duplicate names, name all columns in that case explicitly).

Comment: From what I can see it seems to be creating the rows but not properly.